# share audio file with whatsapp (file format not supported error)

Tags: java, android, file, audio, voice

I'm trying to make a button for sharing an audio file.I get the file format not supported error.I tried all types but always gave the same error(audio/mpeg,audio/aac,audio/wav,audio/ogg,audio/midi,audio/x-ms-wma)
here my codes

```
 button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        File f = new File("ses.mp3");
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                        share.setType("audio/mp3");
                        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        mactivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Song Shared Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

[image]

Comment: my permission =   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: First, you should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`, if you are running this on Android 7.0 or higher. Second, `new File("ses.mp3")` will result in an invalid `File` object on all versions of Android. Where is this file on the device? Perhaps we can point you to a better way to construct the `File` object.

Comment: my voice resource path res/raw/ses.mp3

Comment: Resources are not files on the filesystem. There is no easy way to share a raw resource with another app. My recommendation is to copy the resource to a file (use `Resources` and `openRawResource()` to get a stream to use to make the copy). Then, use `FileProvider` to share that file.

Comment: I'm very new on android where can I find the sample code

Comment: If you are very new on Android, perhaps you would be better served learning Android app development from a book or a course. You can download a free older edition of one of my books from [this page](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free). [Version 7.2](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-7.2-CC.pdf) is the most recent of those right now, and it contains an example along the lines of what you need. However, it uses `assets/` instead of `res/raw/` and uses `ACTION_VIEW` instead of `ACTION_SEND`. See the `FileProvider` section starting on page 2088.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to use this Intent

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

```
   share.setType("*/*");

   File imageFileToShare = new File(f.getAbsolutePath());

    Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile
            (mactivity,mactivity.getPackageName()+".provider",imageFileToShare);

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

mactivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File"));